# Usage of IronKey encrypted USB

Tags: encryption, usb-drive

I used an encrypted IRONKEY USB disk in Windows, and automatically  I was asked to install the software/application for installation and used the password to access the content in it.
How can use the same USB with the same characteristics and keep it undammaged (i.e., encrypted) and use the same procedure. Actually the icon and installation procedure do not appear in Ubuntu.

Comment: If you want to encrypt the data on a drive (whether external or internal) and use it with Windows and Linux (and OS X), I recommend [TCNext](https://truecrypt.ch/) (formerly the now discontinued [TrueCrypt](https://truecrypt.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

The software that encrypts the stick is most probably only available for *Microsoft Windows*.
While you *may* have luck getting that to run in `wine` I highly doubt that it'll function properly.

Comment: Thanks for the indication. I fogured out about "wine", and see if it will help.

Comment: I don't think Wine implements the Windows API to mount file systems and inject a cryptography module in the kernel in the process.

Comment: Yepp, and that's the reason for my serious doubts that it'll work.